# AWS Lambda function to create another AWS lambda function

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cron, aws-lambda

I want my app to invoke a lambda function. The lambda function should create an instance of a lambda function, make the instance a sort of a cron job which runs every hour for upto N times (N = 1000), and pass event keys to the lambda function.

The pseudocode for the lambda function which does the bulk of the work is:

- newLamdaFunc = create from another lambda function
- set a trigger for newLambdaFunc (make it a cron job)
- newLambdaFunc.event.someKey = someValue

Is the above logic possible from within a lambda function? What should be the alternate logic if the above is not possible to do?

Comment: @Carcigenicate This question refers to AWS lambda.

Comment: Ahh, my bad. I'm not familiar with those.

Answer (score 0):

You might have solved it but here is what i'd do
in main lambda I'd just invoke another lambda function lamda.invoke(params: functionname.., other values).
And that will start new lambda.

Answer (score 0):

AWS-CDK allows you to create lambdas from the code. [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-lambda-readme.html)

```js
import lambda = require('@aws-cdk/aws-lambda');

const lambdaFn = new lambda.Function(this, 'MyFunction', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_8_10,
    handler: 'index.handler',
    code: lambda.Code.fromInline('exports.handler = function(event, ctx, cb) { return cb(null, "hi"); }'),
});
```

You can put pretty much any code there.
The next thing you need to do is define the event source. For your use-case I would go with [aws-events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/aws-events-readme.html).
Here is an example:

```js
import events = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events');
import targets = require('@aws-cdk/aws-events-targets');

const rule = new events.Rule(this, 'Rule', {
    schedule: events.Schedule.expression('cron(0 * * * *)')
});

rule.addTarget(new targets.LambdaFunction(lambdaFn));
```

[Here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/lambda-cron/index.ts) you can find an example written in TypeScript